# При выборе значения select изменить значения в другом select-e

Tags: html, jsp, servlet, jstl

Добрый день! Возникла проблема с реализацией такой, что если выбрать значение в одном selecte, то изменяться значения в другом. К примеру, есть список отделений больницы и при выборе конкретного отделения в select, то выводятся доктора именно этого отделения. Суть заключается в том, что если выбрать значение в select отделений, а потом отослать на сервлет, для того чтобы поменяло значение в select докторов, то список конкретных докторов меняется, а значение селекта отделений возвращается на начальный.
Вопрос: как реализовать это так, чтобы после отправки формы на сервлет и отображения селекта с конкретными докторами, значение первого селекта не изменялось?

Вот мой код:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="controller" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="insertNewReception"/>
    Отделение: <select class="selectpicker">
        <option  onclick="location.href='/Task/controller?command=listCategory&category=neurologCategory&reception=new';">
            <c:if test="${category=='Невропатологическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option onclick="location.href='/Task/controller?command=listCategory&category=oftalmologCategory&reception=new';">
            <c:if test="${category=='Офтальмологическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option onclick="location.href='/Task/controller?command=listCategory&category=pediatrCategory&reception=new';">
            <c:if test="${category=='Детское'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option onclick="location.href='/Task/controller?command=listCategory&category=terapevtCategory&reception=new';">
            <c:if test="${category=='Терапевтическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>           
    </select>
    Врач: <select class="selectpicker">
    <c:forEach var="doctor" items="${listCategoryDoctors}">
        <option>${doctor.lastName}</option>
    </c:forEach>        
    </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Записать</button>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Буду рад любому ответу!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, не стоит изменения в первом `select` фиксировать в `onclick` у элементов `option`. Это неверный подход. Я, к примеру, зачастую выбираю значения в выпадающих списках с помощью клавиатуры и ваш `onclick` не сработает.

Нужно использовать именно для этого и предназначенное событие `change` на элементе `select`: http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/onchange

Во-вторых, я порекомендовал бы использовать для получения значений второго `select` ajax-запрос, который произведет получение данных и перерисовку `select` без обновления страницы.

Но если вам не хочется что-то сильно менять в логике работы - нужно просто передавать текущее выбранное в первом `select` значение на вторую страницу, где соответствующему `option` выставлять аттрибут `selected`.

В вашем случае, код будет примерно таким:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="controller" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="command" value="insertNewReception"/>
    Отделение: <select class="selectpicker" onchange="location='/Task/controller?command=listCategory&category='+this.value+'&reception=new'">
        <option value="neurologCategory" ${param.category == "neurologCategory" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
            <c:if test="${category=='Невропатологическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option value="oftalmologCategory" ${param.category == "oftalmologCategory" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
            <c:if test="${category=='Офтальмологическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option value="pediatrCategory" ${param.category == "pediatrCategory" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
            <c:if test="${category=='Детское'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
        <option value="terapevtCategory" ${param.category == "terapevtCategory" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}>
            <c:if test="${category=='Терапевтическое'}">
                <c:out value="${category}"></c:out>
            </c:if>
        </option>
    </select>
    Врач: <select class="selectpicker">
        <c:forEach var="doctor" items="${listCategoryDoctors}">
            <option>${doctor.lastName}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Записать</button>
    <br/>
</form>
```

Насчет части `${param.category == "terapevtCategory" ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}` не уверен, малознаком с синтаксисом, но надеюсь поправите, если есть ошибка.